# Can I use enterprise.jar/metadata.jar generated from one org to establish connection with different org?

Tags: soap-api, java

I have generated jar from enterprise.wsdl for some java development. I wonder if i could use the same jar to establish connection to different salesforce org having different enterprise.wsdl file?

**UPDATE:**
I tried to retrieve metadata of different org using [RetrieveSample](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve.htm),it threw below error.

[image: Error]

However I managed to obtain **sessionid** using same jar with [sample java code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm).

[image: Session id]

Is there any other way to retrieve metadata using session id?

Answer (score 2):

**Enterprise.wsdl** are tightly bound to a specific salesforce organization. **You can't use** Jar created from that to integrate with other orgs.

**Partner.wsdl** is the one which is loosely bound and can be used for integration with any salesforce organization.

This information is provided in the API page itself:

[image]

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004760&language=en_US&type=1)